# Trigonometry. trying to create a specific formula in C#

Tags: c#, .net, math, trigonometry

I´m trying to create a formula in C#. Specifically for triangle calculation

I dont get the right result and cant seem to figure out how to get

Formula = c = √(b^2+ a^2- 2·b·a·cos⁡(C)

Picture of Formula = [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9isc.png)

in the formula, the objective is to find little c.

When you know big C, small a and small b

this is my code

```
        public double returnC(double C, double a, double b)
    {

        double number2 = 2;

        double potentiationfora = Math.Pow(a, 2);
        double potentiationforb = Math.Pow(b, 2);

        double CalculationPart1 = number2 * b;
        double CalculationPart2 = a * Math.Cos(C);
        double CalculationPart3 = CalculationPart1 * CalculationPart2;

        double PotensCombiner = potentiationfora + potentiationforb;
        double CalculationPart4 = PotensCombiner - CalculationPart3;

        double cResult = Math.Sqrt(CalculationPart4);

        return cResult;
    }
```

CalculationPart2 should get 6.427876 but I get 9.649660

Comment: What is your question? What does the code do? Does it compile, work, or not work? What is the outcome?

Comment: Were you testing something with that `Math.Cos(50)` bit? Be aware that this function takes its argument value in radians, not degrees.

Comment: The part calculating cResult should be
 double cResult = Math.Pow(CalculationPart4, 0.5);

Comment: With your expected result can you edit in the values of a, b, C that you're using please? (I can only guess that's why people don't think this is a complete enough example :-/ )

Comment: You've edited the question to switch to using Sqrt. Does that change the values you're getting? (The issue is now probably that you're passing C in degrees whereas Math.Cos expects radians, as in 500's comment and J.'s answer.)

Comment: Yes you can edit in the values of a, b and C its supposed to into a forms app

Comment: Unless you never heard of C# expression syntax, your code is very contrived. 


Why don't you simply use  `return Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b - 2 * a * b * Math.Cos(C));` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.Cos(50)? why not C? also note that Math.Cos takes An angle, measured in radians.
Also double cResult = Math.Pow(1, CalculationPart4); this doesnt seem right, use Math.Sqrt

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Which part of my conclusion are you talking about?

Comment: All of them. I have trouble reading the question and translating that to your answer.

Comment: OP posted the formula. Formula has square root at the end, but he's function uses Math.Pow. Also he don's use C argument in Math.Cos function which is also stated in OP's formula

Comment: How do i change it to Radians

Comment: public double ConvertToRadians(double angle)
    {
        return (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
    }

Answer (score 2):

```
public double returnC(double C, double a, double b)
{
    double a2 = Math.Pow(a, 2);
    double b2 = Math.Pow(b, 2);
    double _2abcosc = 2 * a * b * Math.Cos(C);
    // if c is a degree then 
    //double _2abcosc = 2 * a * b * Math.Cos(C*Math.PI/180);
    return Math.Sqrt( a2 + b2 - _2abcosc);
}
```

Comment: And this will not work

Comment: @Reniuz would you please tell why wouldn't it work?

Comment: C is angle and Math.Cos takes angle in radians as a parameter.

Comment: You want `Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * C))`

Comment: @Reniuz yeah I got that and corrected in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

var result = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(b, 2) + Math.Pow(a, 2)) - (2 * b * a * Math.Cos(C)));